# Git: How to move origin/master from an abandoned branch to current HEAD?

Tags: git, git-checkout

Git newbie here. I made some changes that I wanted to abandon. So I did a checkout to an earlier point, and started working again. I don't recall exactly what else I did, but here is my current situation (as displayed by PyCharm):

[image: Git log]

HEAD is at the top (comment: "Typo"). origin/master are on the version whose comment is "Notes on redirection.

I pushed to github and HEAD didn't show up there. I understand that I need to made the Typo version my current origin/master. How do I do that?

I am the only developer, nobody is going to be affected by any changes. I don't care if the two versions on the dead end (ending in "Notes on redirection") are permanently deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently in a ["detached HEAD" state](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/detached-head-when-checkout-commit), meaning there is no active branch. You can have your `master` branch point to you current revision ("Typo") using this command:

```
git switch --force-create master
```

After that you can push using the `--force-with-lease` option. This is required because the push will abandon the two revisions "out and store ..." and "Notes on ...":

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

> So I did a checkout to an earlier point, and started working again.

The right command to use would be `git reset --hard <commit-ID>`. This avoids the "detached HEAD" state. Note that for the first push after that operation you still need to use the `--force-with-lease` option.

Comment: Note that you must also `git checkout master` after the command sequence in this answer to get out of the "detached HEAD" state and to progress `master` when you make further commits.

Comment: @j6t I missed that, thanks for pointing it out. I changed my answer to use `git switch --force-create master` to do the branch and checkout in one step.

Answer (score 0):

A branch in Git is just a string, a name pointing to a single commit. The way to get yourself back to "More reversion", when you decided you were going down the wrong road, was not to use `checkout` but rather to use `reset --hard`, which simply picks up the current branch name and repoints it to wherever you specify.

And you can use that same technique now to fix the problem! First make a branch to hold your place. Then jump back to the master pointer that you accidentally abandoned, and repoint it to where you are now:

```
git switch -c temp
git switch master
git reset --hard temp
```

You no longer need the placeholder, so delete it:

```
git branch -D temp
```

By the way, this sort of thing is why you should not develop on master — even when you are the only user of the repo. If you had been on an experimental branch when you decided your strategy was a failure, you could simply have abandoned the branch, switched back to master, and started a new branch with a different line of experimentation.

Comment: I am trying to follow @matt's steps. I created a branch named fix-detached-head, and switched to master. I then tried "git reset --hard fix-detached-head" which failed: "fatal: ambiguous argument 'fix-detached-head': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Comment: The implication is that you didn't actually do what I said (because what I said works, I enacted it while writing the answer, to be absolutely sure). Can you say more about what you did?

Comment: I created a branch: branch fixed-detached-head. Then: (I.e., temp=fixed-detached-head). Then: git switch fix-detached-head Then: git switch master. Then: git reset --hard fix-detached-head, and saw the error message I posted. (On my first read of your post I didn't realize that switch -c created the branch, which is why I created the branch using "git branch".)

Comment: It is entirely possible that I unintentionally deviated from what you wrote (and from I reported in the previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

> I created a branch: `branch fixed-detached-head`.
> Then: (I.e., temp=fixed-detached-head). Then: `git switch fix-detached-head`

It is better to create a branch directly with [`git switch -c`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--cltnew-branchgt), from another branch/commit, that way, you avoid the all "detached HEAD" situation.

```
git switch -c newBranch oldBranchOrCommit
```